# How can I delete an item from my todolist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to learn react js , but I don't know how to delete an item from my list, could you help me ? Actually, I am not professional , but I am really interested in learning, there is my codes which add some new item to my list properly, but I don't know how to delete them when I click on their checkbox/delete button.

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
    const App = () => {
      const [NewTaskText, setNewTaskText] = useState("");
      const [Tasks, setTasks] = useState(["do a task", "samira"]);
    
      const addTask = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!NewTaskText) return;
        setTasks((currentTasks) => {
          return [...currentTasks, NewTaskText];
        });
        setNewTaskText("");
      };
    
      const onchangeInput = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        setNewTaskText(value);
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="row">
          <form onSubmit={addTask}>
            <div className="row col s6">
              <div className="input-field col s10">
                <textarea
                  id="textarea1"
                  className="materialize-textarea"
                  value={NewTaskText}
                  onChange={onchangeInput}
                ></textarea>
    
                <label htmlFor="textarea1">What needs to be done ?</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          
    
          <div className="row col s6">
            <br></br>
            <a className='waves-effect waves-light btn' href="/#" onClick={addTask}>
                <i className='material-icons left' >
                  add_circle
                </i>
                Add
              </a>
          </div>
          </form>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="row col s9">
              <ul className="collection with-header">
                <li className="collection-header">
                  <h4>Todo List</h4>
    
                  <form>
                    <div className="input-field">
                      <input id="search" type="search" required />
                      <label className="label-icon" htmlFor="search">
                        <i className="material-icons">search</i>Search
                      </label>
                      <i className="material-icons">close</i>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </li>
                <label>
                 
                  {Tasks.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                     
                      <li className="collection-item" key={i}>
                       
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        <span>
                       
                          {item}
                          </span>
                      
                        <span>
                          <a href="#!" className="secondary-content">
                            <i className="material-icons" >delete</i>
                            <i className="material-icons">check_circle</i>
                          </a>
                        </span>
                     
                      </li>
                     
                    );
                  })}
                
                </label>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default App;
```

Comment: if a solution worked for you make sure to accept it as the answer

Comment: Sinan Yaman i pressed "votes" button , right ?

Comment: You can upvote or mark the answer as accepted by clicking the `check` mark under the votes section. Btw, I am not saying you have to do this, but this is generally the flow of stackoverflow, so you are welcome to do so :)

Comment: @Sinan Yaman : dear sinan , i did it , and it is kind of you , actually i am begginer and i wasnt familiar with the flow of stackoverflow so i asked you . thanks for your response.

Comment: No problem, happy coding! :)

Comment: thanks a billion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the item from the array by using index:

```
<i className="material-icons" onClick={() => handleDelete(i)}>delete</i>
```

and define your function above the return statement:

```
const handleDelete = i => {
  const taskList = [...Tasks]
  taskList.splice(i, 1)
  setTasks(taskList)
}
```

Here it is important to know that you have to make a copy of the state if it is an `object` or an `array`. Because if you modify the original array or object, react won't register that as a change, and won't re-render. That is why I did `const taskList = [...Tasks]`. You can also use a library like `lodash` which provides some neat ways of handling objects and arrays

Answer (score 0):

Just add a onClick handler to button which should delete item

```
<i className="material-icons" onClick={ () => {
    setTasks((prevTasks) => {
        const updatedPrevTasks = [...prevTasks];
        updatedPrevTasks.splice(i, 1);

        return updatedPrevTasks;
    });
}}>delete</i>
```

Comment: A small but crucial typo, should be `updatedPrevTasks.splice(i, 1);` and you have to use an arrow function inside the `onClick`, otherwise react will run the function without the need of a click